# Unable to attach a rule to a security policy in Google Cloud Armor using Pulumi

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pulumi, google-cloud-armor, pulumi-python

I want to attach a rate-based throttling rule to a security policy, all via Pulumi, in Google Cloud Armor, on Google Cloud Platform.

I am facing an error:

```
Diagnostics:
  gcp:compute:SecurityPolicy (ddos-layer7-defense-policy):
    error: gcp:compute/securityPolicy:SecurityPolicy resource 'ddos-layer7-defense-policy' has a problem: Attribute must be a list. Examine values at 'ddos-layer7-defense-policy.rules'.
```

In my code, I am providing a `list` of one variable. That variable is of type `gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleArgs`. Yet, I face an issue of not providing coherent type input.

Definition of the rule:

```
rate_based_throttling_rule = gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleArgs(
    action="throttle",
    match=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleMatchArgs(
        config=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleMatchConfigArgs(
            src_ip_ranges='*'
        )
    ),
    priority=110,
    description='Rate based throttling for security policies. Currently, in preview mode.',
    preview=True,
    rate_limit_options=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleRateLimitOptionsArgs(
        conform_action="allow",
        exceed_action="deny(429)",
        rate_limit_threshold=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleRateLimitOptionsRateLimitThresholdArgs(
            count=100,
            interval_sec=60
        )
    )
)
```

Definition of the policy:

```
ddos_layer7_defense_policy_name = "ddos-layer7-defense-policy"
layer7_ddos_defense_config_var = gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyAdaptiveProtectionConfigLayer7DdosDefenseConfigArgs(
    enable=True
)
adaptive_protection_args_var = gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyAdaptiveProtectionConfigArgs(
    layer7_ddos_defense_config=layer7_ddos_defense_config_var
)
ddos_layer7_defense_policy = gcp.compute.SecurityPolicy(
    ddos_layer7_defense_policy_name,
    project=gcp_project,
    description="Policy for enabling DDoS defence on L7",
    name="{}-{}".format(ddos_layer7_defense_policy_name, gcp_subdomain),
    adaptive_protection_config=adaptive_protection_args_var,
    rules=[rate_based_throttling_rule]
)
```

The documentation for the `rules` parameter in `SecurityPolicy` is:

```
rules: Input[Sequence[Input[InputType[SecurityPolicyRuleArgs]]]] | None = None,
```

Comment: Is this the [documentation](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/compute/securitypolicy/) you followed?